# I can't read database information in activity from fragment in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm beginner in android programmation but and I have difficulty to read `sqlite` database information in activity from fragment.

That is my Fragment activity:

```
package cm.mavis.easylife.les_fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import cm.mavis.easylife.ChoixRecherche;
import cm.mavis.easylife.DataHelper;
import cm.mavis.easylife.LectureInfos;
import cm.mavis.easylife.R;

public class FragmentRecherche extends Fragment {
String[] liste;
protected Cursor cursor;
DataHelper dbcenter;
ListView  listview;
public static Context fragmentRecherche;


public static FragmentRecherche newInstance() {
    FragmentRecherche fragment = new FragmentRecherche();
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recherche, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ChoixRecherche.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    listview = rootView.findViewById(R.id.liste_recherche);

    fragmentRecherche = getActivity();
    dbcenter = new DataHelper(getActivity());
    RefreshList();


    return rootView;
}

public void RefreshList() {
SQLiteDatabase database = dbcenter.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from cni_perdu", null);
liste = new String[cursor.getCount()];
cursor.moveToFirst();

for (int cc = 0; cc < cursor.getCount(); cc++){
    cursor.moveToPosition(cc);
    liste[cc] = cursor.getString(1);
}

listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste));
listview.setSelected(true);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        final String selection = liste[arg2];
        final CharSequence[] dialogitem = {"Voir", "Suprimer"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Option");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.mes_voyage);
        builder.setItems(dialogitem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){
                switch (item){
                    case 0:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LectureInfos.class);
                        intent.putExtra("", selection);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        RefreshList();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        SQLiteDatabase database = dbcenter.getWritableDatabase();
                        database.execSQL("delete from cni_perdu where prenom = '" + selection + "'");
                        dbcenter.close();
                        RefreshList();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
});
    ((ArrayAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();

}
@Override
}

  int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

And that is my activity:

```
package cm.mavis.easylife;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LectureInfos extends AppCompatActivity {
DataHelper dataHelper;
protected Cursor cursor;
TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_infos);

    dataHelper = new DataHelper(this);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);

    SQLiteDatabase database = dataHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM cni_perdu where nom = '" +
            getIntent().getStringExtra("nom") + "'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(0);
        textView1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        textView2.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        textView3.setText(cursor.getString(3));
        textView4.setText(cursor.getString(4));
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute my app, I have this result

[image]

But I want to obtain this result:

[image]

Please help me!

edit: excuse me if I duplicate one topic but after a many searching I don't find a positive result. Also excuse me if my English is poor I'm a French-speaking;

Cordially!

---

**UPDATE**

that is the code of my database

```
package cm.mavis.easylife;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "piece_perdu.db";
private static final  int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
public DataHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
    String sql = "create table if not exit cni_perdu(nom text null, prenom text null, ville text null, quartier text null);";
    Log.d("Data", "onCreate: "+sql);
    database.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2){

}
}
```

Comment: Is nom, ville are column name of your table?

Comment: Instead of  cursor.moveToPosition(0); use  cursor.moveToFirst();

Comment: i have same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LectureInfos.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nom", selection);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    RefreshList();
                    break;
```

you didnt pass the putExtra Argument Name.

Try

```
 intent.putExtra("nom", selection);
```

And in your DBHelper Class

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
    String sql = "create table if not exists  cni_perdu(nom text null, prenom text null, ville text null, quartier text null);";
    Log.d("Data", "onCreate: "+sql);
    database.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Your syntax is wrong .you wrote " exit " instead of " exists "

Answer (score 1):

Change your `intent.putExtra("", selection);` to `intent.putExtra("nom", selection);` in **FragmentRecherche** class

**Remember**

`intent.putExtra()` always be in the form of key value pair. If you want to get data from `intent`  you have to use the same `key` in `getIntent().getStringExtra()` which you have passed in `intent.putExtra()`

**For Example -:**

sending extras with intent from Activity one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
                    intent.putExtra("foo", message);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

getting extras from intent in Second Activity

```
String msg  = getIntent().getStringExtra("foo");
```

Now, Your code must be to your **FragmentRecherche**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LectureInfos.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nom", selection);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    RefreshList();
                    break;
```

Comment: I have same result when i change this.

Comment: check you are getting data from data base using log. I think the problem is in your database code

Comment: I use this database in another activity and it work. i think the probleme come to my fragment activity.